# Python passing user input of name of file to open

Tags: python, input, filenames

I don't understand why something this simple isn't very intuitive.

This is what I have so far:

```
    print("Enter name of file on Desktop:")
    filename = sys.stdin.readline()


    directory = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),"Desktop")
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.startswith(filename):
                    f = open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r+', encoding="Latin-1")
                    data = f.read()
                    print(data)
                    f.close()
```

Why can't I pass the sys.stdin that was assigned to the variable filename 
to the 'if' statement:

```
   `if file.startswith(filename):`?
```

I tried:

```
    if file.startswith(str(filename)):
    if file.startswith("'" + filename + "'")
    if file.startswith(filename):
```

no options seem to "go through" and no errors pop up.

It just pretends like I didn't pass anything. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Format code by indenting by four spaces. Only use backticks for small pieces of code.

Comment: Also, any time you get errors, you need to post them

Answer (score 2):

A line, whether read from stdin or from a file, includes a newline character. It seems unlikely that any of your filenames end in a newline.

But don't use `sys.stdin.readline` to get input from the user. Use the appropriately-named `input` function:

```
filename = input("Enter name of file on Desktop:")
```

(Note, in Python 2.x you should use `raw_input` rather than `input`.)

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. Thanks. I got it to work.